# On Robin's criterion for the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Statement 1 : (Robin) proved that if the R.H. is false then there exist constants $0<\beta <\frac{1}{2}$ and $c>0$ small , such that $\sum \limits_{d|n} d \geq e^\gamma n \ln \ln n+ n\frac{ c \ln \ln n}{\ln^\beta n}$ holds for infinitely many $n$.

Statement 2 :  if the R.H. is false then there exist constants $0<\beta <\frac{1}{2}$ and $c>0$ small , such that $\prod \limits_{p \leq n} \frac{p}{p-1} \geq e^\gamma \ln \theta(n)+ \frac{ c  \ln \theta(n)}{\theta^\beta(n)}$ holds for infinitely many $n$.

Does Statement 1 imply Statement 2 ?!

Update : Posted On MSE

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged. Also your title doesn't describe the problem at all.

Comment: As Statement 1 is true, you are simply asking if Statement 2 is true.

Comment: @GHfromMO yes, does 1 imply 2 or equivalent ?

Comment: If 1 implies 2, then both are true (as 1 is known to be true), so they are equivalent. My point is that the way you ask the question is somewhat silly. You should have simply asked if Statement 2 is true or not, and use Statement 1 as motivation only.

Comment: @GHfromMO o.k. , will do next time , thanks . is 2 true ?

Comment: I've replaced the former useless title "Does Statement 1 imply Statement 2". Feel free to improve it further

Comment: I've put the papers [there](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Zeta_Riemann/RobinCriterion/) @GHfromMO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Statement 2 was proved by Jean-Louis Nicolas: see Theorem 3 in [*Petites valeurs de la fonction d'Euler*, Journal of Number Theory, 17 (1983), 375-388](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X83900550). More precisely, Statement 2 follows from the bound $\varliminf x^b\log f(x)<0$ in part (c) of the quoted theorem, upon noting that $\theta(x)\asymp x$ (Chebyshev's theorem).